# How to convert Guava HashMultmap to java.util.Map

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

I am trying to convert Guava `Multimap<String ,Collection<String>>` into `Map<String, Collection<String>>` but I get a syntax error when using `Multimaps.asMap(multimap)`. Here is a code:

```
HashMultimap<String, Collection<String>> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
for (UserDTO dto : employees) {
    if (dto.getDepartmentNames() != null) {
        multimap.put(dto.getUserName().toString().trim(), dto.getDepartmentNames());
    }
}
Map<String, Collection<String>> mapOfSets = Multimaps.asMap(multimap);
```

Here is a screenshot of error:
[image]

Can someone point out where I am doing a mistake?

Comment: Why don't you define the `mapOfSets` as `Map<String, Set<String>>`?

Comment: Method which i have return is returning Map<String, Collection<String>> so that i need the same return type.

Comment: I already check this all of my imports are using guava API not Apache

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's not the case - compare to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return type of `Multimaps.asMap(multimap)` is `Map<String, <Set<Collection<String>>`.

Multimap can hold multiple values of the same key. Hence, when you want to convert from multimap to a map, you need to keep collection of values for each key, just in case, there is a key which appears twice in the map.

If you want to convert from `MultiMap` to `Map` and make set sum on the values, you can do the following:

```
Multimaps.asMap(multimap).entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                 Map.Entry::getKey,
                 e->e.getValue().stream()
                      .flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(toSet())));
```

Comment: @xentros Thanks for hint. it works with   Map<String, Set<Collection<String>>> mapOfSets = Multimaps.asMap(multimap); I am still confused how i would get Map<String, Collection<String>> from this as my method signature are different ?

Comment: Yes i got it. Have a problem in my project regarding guava versioning. Rest seems to be a perfect implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing here is using `Multimap` wrong. `Multimap<String, Collection<String>>` is roughly an equivalent to `Map<String, Collection<Collection<String>>>`, so it results in nested collections when using `asMap` view (ex. `{user1=[[IT, HR]], user2=[[HR]], user3=[[finance]]}`).

What you really want is to use `Multimap<String, String>` (more specifically: `SetMultimap<String, String>` which corresponds to `Map<String, Set<String>>`) and use [`Multimap#putAll(K, Iterable<V>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#putAll-K-java.lang.Iterable-):

```
SetMultimap<String, String> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
for (UserDTO dto : employees) {
    if (dto.getDepartmentNames() != null) {
        // note `.putAll` here
        multimap.putAll(dto.getUserName().toString().trim(), dto.getDepartmentNames());
    }
}
Map<String, Set<String>> mapOfSets = Multimaps.asMap(multimap);
// ex. {user1=[HR, IT], user2=[HR], user3=[finance]}
```

Using [`Multimaps#asMap(SetMultimap)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap-com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap-) instead of [`SetMultimap#asMap()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html#asMap--) is necessary due to Java type system limitation (can't override generic type in a subtype when its nested in a generic type):

> Note: The returned map's values are guaranteed to be of type `Set`. To
>   obtain this map with the more specific generic type `Map<K, Set<V>>`,
>   call `Multimaps.asMap(SetMultimap)` instead.